# How to save an image in UV/Image Editor with grease pencil strokes visible?

Tags: rendering, image, grease-pencil

I made a few grease pencil strokes over an image displayed in UV/Image Editor, is there a way to save an image that includes those strokes (except making a screenshot)?

Using "Save as Image" saves only the original picture:

[image: grease pencil]

Comment: Just gotta say, sick render!

Comment: the render is not mine, I'm only commenting on a render made in Blender by another person :) namely pointing to the texture repetitions visible

Comment: I think screenshot is going to be the way to go. Is there some other problem with doing it that way?

Comment: The problem is, I will need it many times in the future, it's not convenient and wasteful to create screenshots of entire interface and send them back to artists with my comments.

Comment: I think in this case it would make more sence to use something link GIMP or photoshop to do the draw over, simply because they are designed for this type of thing.

Comment: I think that request is fully legit. If grease pencil can be used for animation production why not use it for simple render/texture commenting. Meanwhile this also needs a feature of text being added along the pencil.
I suggest that you create a feature request to devs. This way you contribute to Blender development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most obvious workaround is to not use Grease Pencil at all and use texture painting instead. The "mode" button should be switched from "View" to "Paint" and then all the paint strokes are saved with "Save as Image" option.

[image: paint mode]

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL will render your what you see in the viewport. To render using OpenGL, click render > OpenGL render image

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't answer the question, because OpenGL render will render what is in *viewport* while the question is about exporting modified inside Blender image from *UV / Image Editor*.

Comment: Sorry, I happened to overlook that.

Comment: alternatively, you could add the image as a plane in the viewport. enable the addon "import images as planes" then open file > import > images as planes.

Comment: @MrZak the accepted answer didn't answer the question either, and yet...